# How can I sum even numbers within a range, using shell?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have to take 2 parameters for the command line. The first parameter is the starting number and the second parameter is the number of integers. Here is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
x=$1
y=$2
z=0
k=$((x%2))
while [ $z -lt $y ]; do
  if [ $k == 0 ]; then
    echo $k
  fi
  x=$((x+1))
  echo $((x+1))
  k=$((x%2))
  z=$((z+1))
done
```

Is there anyone that can help me with this program, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I believe that this can be solved in closed form, so there is no need for any looping. Do the math!

Comment: This is not a question, but a program specification.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's only a problem with how the question title is worded, not with the question itself; why don't you edit that to make it better.

Comment: @Kaz, is it? I don't see a question here at all, except for "[i]s there anyone that can help me with this program?".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The problem to be solved is clear, and the user shows what he/she has tried so far, and it's about programming.

Comment: The title is a program specification. The only *question* given is whether a person who can help exists. Apparently the answer is "yes", and that person yourself. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Your user name has to be SheldonCooper for that to be funny.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You might flunk computer science with your approach. "Professor, you said to answer as many questions of the midterm as possible in the time given. But all I saw was imperative statements, like prove this, that and another thing, and show all the steps."

Comment: Well -- **now** there's actually a well-formed question. And I appreciate the chuckle. :)

Comment: @Kaz ...and apparently not so clear -- spec didn't indicate whether the "number of integers" was a pre- or post-filter count

Answer (score 1):

1. Determine the first and last integer in the series, m and n.
2. Round up m to the nearest even integer to produce m'
3. Round down n to the nearest even integer produce n'
4. Now calculate  (m' + n') * (m' - n' + 2) / 4

This formula obviously works in the base case where we have m' = n' (both being even of course), reducing to (m' + m') * 2 / 4 = m'. Proof: exercise for reader.

How about an example: add up even integers in the range starting at 7 that includes 15 integers.

1. m = 7, n = 7 + 15 - 1 = 21
2. m' = 8
3. n' = 20
4. (m' + n') * (m' - n' + 2) / 4 = (8 + 20) * (20 - 8 + 2) / 4 = 28 * 14 / 4 = 98

Check the result

```
$ echo $(( 8 + 10 + 12 + 14 + 16 + 18 + 20 ))
98
```

Bash code: exercise for reader.

Comment: You will have to adjust this a little if the second parameter represents the number of even numbers to add together, rather than the number of consecutive integers from the first parameter.

Comment: Oh yea I see what you mean, because at first that was the problem, but I fixed it. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here's a first cut:

```
#!/bin/bash
cur=$1
max=$(( $1 + $2 ))
sum=0

# increment to next even number if starting value is odd
(( cur % 2 == 1 )) && (( ++cur ))
(( max % 2 == 1 )) && (( --max ))

for (( x=cur; x <= max; x+= 2 )); do
  (( sum += x ))
done

echo "$sum"
```

This works as follows:

```
# 4 = 4
$ ./sum-events 3 2
4

# 4 + 6 = 10
$ ./sum-events 4 2
10
```

Comment: it should be 4, because the starting number is 3, for the second parameter 2 was entered so the consecutive numbers would be 4,5 since 4 is the only even number it would be the only number to add

Comment: @user3335209 So take off the multiplier and round down, if that's what you want. That should be an obvious enough change you don't need me to do it for you.

Comment: ...eh. Updated to spec.

Comment: Please try to ask a more explicit question next time -- answers might be provided with less snark. :)